Frequency response open circuit time constant having trouble finding the resistance of a certain capacitor

*The problem (Fig.1)
(From Microelectronic Circuits SEDRA/SMITH 7e Fig. 10.40 (b))
I'm finding the 3 dB frequency of this circuit using the open circuit time constant, and I met a problem while finding R_pi1.
I know that exchanging C_pi1 with a voltage/current source helps us find the resistance. And I have a hard time finding Vx/Ix. Node analysis and Mesh analysis isn't the ideal way because sometimes we have to represent it in algebra form. I have no idea how Vx/Ix is derived below in such a clean way.

*Analysis of Cpi1(Fig.2)
(From Microelectronic Circuits SEDRA/SMITH 7e Fig. 10.40 (c))

*The Final Analysis of Cpi1(Fig.3)
(From Microelectronic Circuits SEDRA/SMITH 7e Page 784)
First, how to derive the formula Vx/Ix from (Fig.2) to (Fig.3) ? Second, how to find the value of Vx/Ix easily and works in every circuit? It's okay to answer only the first question but I hope I knew the second one.
Miller's Theorem seems to be a great way to simply the circuit before using the open circuit time constant, but the textbook doesn't use it. I have no idea.

DCtime - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. See the linked rule for details. TY

Edited. Thanks.

Getting a "low entropy" equation is not an easy task.
You can try to google fast analytical circuit techniques
Two example of using FACT:
Pole location in simple RC circuit
Transfer function of three cascaded filters (including loading)
But you can try to use a KCL and KVL.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So we have:
$$ I_X = I_1 + I_2 $$
$$I_2 = \frac{V_X}{r_{\pi}}$$
$$I_1 = \frac{V_B}{R_{sig}}$$
And KVL
$$V_B = V_X + (I_1 - I_C)R_{in2}$$
And of course
$$I_C = g_m V_X $$
Now we have everything to be able to solve for \$R_X = \frac{V_X}{I_X}\$.
You can try it yourself. And after you get the result try to simplify it.
By replacing \$g_m\$ with this one:
\$\large g_m = \frac{1}{r_e} - \frac{1}{r_{\pi}}\$

Finally I got the answer right. Without defining Ix = I1+I2 and using Vb and the formula of gm its impossible to get the formula right. FACT seems to be a book. The process is tedious.
